# How does such an USB step-up 5V-12V work?

Tags: power-supply, power, usb, dc, step-up

I just bought a cheap USB 5V to 12V step up converter:

[image]

Surprisingly, it works very well. There is few place for electronic components (maybe in the USB connector?), **how can we do a 5V to 12V conversion with such a small size / few components?**

Comment: Obviously there is a boost converter which can be small, easyly fits the mould around type A connector. The power is not more than 2W, so it's a very small current, hence small footprint.

Comment: Have you seen the size of a complete [MT3608 circuit](https://www.ebay.com/itm/MT3608-DC-DC-Step-Up-Boost-Converter-Power-Supply-Module-2V-24V-to-5V-28V-2A/312279747003), lose the adjustable potentiometer, use a smaller 22uH inductor (only needs to be 500mA, not 2A) and those components will go into the USB A plug easily.

Comment: @Neil_UK Awesome ! I'm going to test this MT3608 ! Also do you think there is a step up that can be powered by only 1.2 or 1.5V, i.e. a single AA battery and output up to 12 V? (The one you linked requires 2V at least)

Comment: Ps: if someone knows more or less how it works, could you post ad answer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is called "boost converter", or "DC-DC step-up converter". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmNpsofY4-U

Comment: @Ale..chenski Great video, I think you can post it as an answer + maybe a short summary in 1 or 2 sentences to mention how it works, thanks again!

Comment: I looked for a 1.5V to 9V step up boost converter, not found many on ebay. Does this even exist? (I found many 1V to 3.3V step up, or 1.5V to 5V but only one 1.5V to 9V and not sure if it's good)

Comment: Step-ups that work from low voltages do exist, they're generally called 'power harvesters'. Texas Instruments (TI) seem to have a lot of designs, look at their website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmNpsofY4-U) is an interesting video giving details about the internals of a step up converter.

I bought this item, and here are more details:

[image]

Internal:

[image]

Apart from some resistors and capacitors, there are:

- a [Schottky diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_diode) SS24
- a [3R3](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32806583336.html) power inductor
- an unknown AL877 6-pin chip (?)

---

I also bought this item ("MT3608 DC-DC Step Up Boost Converter Power Supply Module 2V-24V to 5V-28V 2A"):

[image]

I tried to power it with:

- 1 AA battery (1,35V) : non working, the output stayed always at 1.21V
- 2 AA battery (2.7V) : working great, the output can go up to 27.4V !
- 3 AA battery (4V) : working as well

During my test, there was a cool feature (I don't know if it's common or not, or which chip is responsible for this): no matter the input voltage (2.7V or 4V), the output voltage only depended on the position of the potentiometer. Ex: I set the out voltage to 9.00V when using two AA batteries.
Then I plugged 3 AA batteries without moving the potentiometer. The out voltage stayed at 9.01V, this is interesting!

I wonder if there exists step up converters able to convert 1 AA battery (let's say 1.4V) to 9V, I haven't found any in the same micro-size PCB.

---

Interesting reading: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an19fc.pdf

Comment: As this stands, this is not a very good answer. I'm not sure just how lax we are on here with self-answers, but I do recommend elaborating on this some more!

Comment: I just converted it to community wiki so if some people wise enough about it can add a few lines, the answer can be improved.

Comment: This is now a much better answer. Good one! Judging by the traces going to it and the fact that there has to be one _somewhere_, I'd guess that AL877 is probably a boost converter controller with an integrated switching element (probably just a MOSFET), and all those capacitors and resistors are probably just support components for that. Some of the resistors probably also set the output voltage (which means you could probably hack this to change it).

Comment: Note that 3R3 on the inductor is not actually a part number; it's a value, probably either 3.3μH or 3.3mH, depending on the marking scheme used by this particular manufacturer.